# Reading from src/main/resources gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, xls

In my Maven project, I have a xls file in src/main/resources.
When I read it like this:

```
 InputStream in = new
 FileInputStream("src/main/resources/WBU_template.xls");
```

everything is ok.

However I want to read it as InputStream with getResourceAsStream. When I do this, with or without the slash I always get a NPE.

```
     private static final String TEMPLATEFILE = "/WBU_template.xls";
     InputStream in = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream(TEMPLATEFILE);
```

No matter if the slash is there or not, or if I make use of the getClassLoader() method, I still get a NullPointer.

I also have tried this :

```
URL u = this.getClass().getResource(TEMPLATEFILE);
System.out.println(u.getPath());
```

the console says.../target/classes/WBU_template.xls 
and then get my NullPointer.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

FileInputStream will load a the file path you pass to the constructor as relative from the working directory of the Java process.

[getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) will load a file path relative from your application's classpath.

When you use `.getClass().getResource(fileName)` it considers the location of the fileName is the same location of the of the calling class.

When you use `.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)`
it considers the location of the fileName is the root - in other words bin folder.

The file should be located in `src/main/resources` when loading using Class loader

In short, you have to use `.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)` to load the file in your case.

Comment: Thanks. This was clear so far. Problem is that in this way I still can not access the xls file in the src/main/resources folder.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, please try using .getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)

Comment: Also, remove the slash from your fileName. /WBU_template.xls => WBU_template.xls

Comment: This works fine when I run the app from IDE, but when i compile application in to jar file its always looking for path myjar.jar!\myfile.txt. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I usually load files from WEB-INF like this

```
session.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/WBU_template.xls")
```